# Android Studio Blank Activity Compilation Fails

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been coding for a few years now and decided it was time to sink my teeth into android development. So I downloaded the latest version of Android Studio and installed all the relevant components with the installer.

However when i try to create a new project, using the blank activity, without even changing a single line of code, or editing the project in any way, the compile fails with the below error:

```
android execution failed for task :app:packageDebug
> Implementing Class
```

I have no idea of to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post contents from build.gradle under app folder?

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.officialpiaddict.test2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same error message.  This is what I have found out:

I have a Mac Book Air with a Custom OS Image installed (from work) and on this computer I see the same error message above even from a fresh install (custom image) and fresh install of JavaRE and JDK as per the Android Studio System Requirements.  Also a fresh install of Android Studio using a Blank activity with no additional lines of code.

However, I reinstalled OS X 10.10 from scratch, straight from the App store, with no OS customizations, installed the same JavaRE, JDK and Android Studio and the Error message did not appear.

I have been scratching my head over this error for a while now and this is the only solution that I have found.  I'll keep digging and report back if I find a better solution.

Comment: Thanks :) Ill definetly try that out. Its probably time for a fresh install anyway.